# visual studio 2010 how to reference a folder inside a project?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have added a folder with a bunch of images inside my vs2010 project. 
I want to reference this folder through code.
Since the final prog may be deployed into different location absolute path won't do!

What is the standard way to get the folders relative path?

I am fairly new to this, so sorry if I am asking something too obvious!
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add images to the resources file, so you will be able to work directly with an image without writing code to find the file.

Anyway, you can get the application path:

```
string appFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
```

And then you can use methods from `Path` class, like `Path.Combine` to refer to the folder.

Comment: the point is that the user of the application must be able to add new pictures to the "Pictures" folder inside the application folder manually.

Comment: The string returned by `.CodeBase` begins with `"file:\"`, which is undesirable. You should use `.Location` instead, which is the pure pathname.

Answer (score 1):

Resources is a good idea.  An alternative is to have the Application's installed folder location written to the Registry when the application is installed. **OR** do something like

```
string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Comment: this sounds like a good idea but I am working on vb.net in wpf and ExecutablePath does not exist in Application

Answer (score 0):

If these images are relative to your executable, then you can either use argv[0] from main() (if it's command line), or even better follow what MSDN is advicing:

> By convention, argv[0] is the command
>   with which the program is invoked.
>   However, it is possible to spawn a
>   process using CreateProcess and if you
>   use both the first and second
>   arguments (lpApplicationName and
>   lpCommandLine), argv[0] may not be the
>   executable name; use GetModuleFileName
>   to retrieve the executable name, and
>   its fully-qualified path.

Comment: I guess you can still access this information, but from .NET (I'm not sure right now how - but anything that gives you the Command Line Arguments, would be close to a function that gives you the process name)... Actually it's been posted below - just saw it - the "AI W" post.